# Using Value from Option to get data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

friends! I've got a json file, a .js file, and some html.

I can read the data from the json file in the js file just fine, and it's outputting to the console.

So I have a  dropdown with all 50 states, and the values are the states abbreviations. Each state was 6 different values like such:

```
"AK": {
  "I": 0,
  "II": 0,
  "III": 0,
  "IV": 0,
  "V": 0,
  "VI": 0
 }
```

I can console the data as such: data.AK.II and it is fine.

I'm having issues achieving this: data.(the value of the option selected).II

```
   $('select#input_56_3').on('change', function () {
var thisValue = $('select#input_56_3 option:selected').val();
var newValue = data.thisValue.I;
console.log('newValue = ' + newValue);
  });
```

This is the error I'm getting, so 'thisValue' is coming across undefined.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'I' of undefined

Should I be converting it some way? I think I've been staring at this too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data.thisValue.II`  to `data[thisValue].II`, it will work.

> - Bracket notation is basically used when there's a space in key names e.g. `"full name"` etc.
> - Do notation is used if you are directly trying to access the values in object. If `d = {k: 1}` then `d.k` and `d[k]` both are fine. `d = {"k v": 1}` then only `d["k v"]` will work.

```
> data = {
...     "AK": {
.....         "I": 0,
.....         "II": 0,
.....         "III": 0,
.....         "IV": 0,
.....         "V": 0,
.....         "VI": 0
.....     }
... }
{ AK: { I: 0, II: 0, III: 0, IV: 0, V: 0, VI: 0 } }
> 
> thisValue = "AK"
'AK'
> 
> data[thisValue].I
0
> data[thisValue].II
0
>
```

The following will throw an exception (error).

```
> data.thisValue.II
Thrown:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'II' of undefined
>
```

Comment: Okay, so now I'm trying to use a different select option to get the last property (I, II, III, IV, V, or VI), but now I'm getting an undefined if I pass it in like this: data[thisValue].loanValue;  

It logs just fine in the console. @hygull

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket notation:

```
var newValue = data[thisValue].I;
```

Comment: and also the dot notation: `data[thisValue].I`

Comment: Whoops, my bad @Steve.